# SQL query refinement for secound count function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my query, but I don't seem to have the SQL correct. Basically I am trying to get column 7 to show the counts from a seperate table (C), but I get an error. Any help? The query works fine without the second count in the select statement, but I'm just trying to get the 7th column to have the counts from another table.

```
select 
    distinct a.auditid,
    a.iav,
    c.VID as 'VMS ID',
    c.severity as 'VMS Severity',
    a.name,
    count (distinct A.dnsname) as 'cat 1s',
    count (distinct c.dnsname) as 'ccri'
from 
    [dbo].[Enterprise 20130703] a
    left join [dbo].[VMS_Retina] c on a.AuditID=c.auditid
    inner join [CCRI 2013] c on a.dnsname=c.DNSName
where
    A.sevcode = 'category i'
    AND A.DNSNAME NOT IN ('autodiscovery,'UNKNOWN')
group by A.auditid, a.iav, a.name, c.VID, c.severity
order by 6 desc
```

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: What's the error? Can you post some sample data?

Comment: You referenced 2 different tables with `c` alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `c` alias for two different tables, change one to other character and query shoul work fine:

```
select 
    distinct a.auditid,
    a.iav,
    c1.VID as 'VMS ID',
    c1.severity as 'VMS Severity',
    a.name,
    count (distinct A.dnsname) as 'cat 1s',
    count (distinct c2.dnsname) as 'ccri'
from
    [dbo].[Enterprise 20130703] a
    left join [dbo].[VMS_Retina] c1 on a.AuditID = c1.auditid
    inner join [CCRI 2013] c2 on a.dnsname = c2.DNSName
where
    A.sevcode = 'category i'
    AND A.DNSNAME NOT IN ('autodiscovery','UNKNOWN')
group by A.auditid, a.iav, a.name, c1.VID, c1.severity
order by 6 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what DBMS you are using but with Oracle Distinct has to be on the top line(s) so maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
A.auditid,
A.iav,
A.VMS ID,
A.VMS Severity,
A.name,
A.cat_1s,
A.ccri
FROM (
    SELECT 
        distinct a.auditid,
        count (distinct A.dnsname) as 'cat_1s',
        count (distinct c.dnsname) as 'ccri'
        a.iav,
        c.VID as 'VMS ID',
        c.severity as 'VMS Severity',
        a.name,
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Enterprise 20130703] a
        left join [dbo].[VMS_Retina] c on a.AuditID=c.auditid
        inner join [CCRI 2013] c on a.dnsname=c.DNSName
    where
        A.sevcode = 'category i'
        AND A.DNSNAME NOT IN ('autodiscovery','UNKNOWN')
    group by A.auditid, a.iav, a.name, c.VID, c.severity
    order by 6 desc
) A
```